# Fetch() calls from Node.js always create new Express sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, fetch

Below is a stripped-down segment of a webshop server with 2 APIs: `./login` to login and `./products` to show products. The products should only be shown after a succesful login.

I'm using TypeScript with Node.js and Express with session management enabled. The code below also tries to test the server by sending `fetch()` requests to the APIs. NOTE: So I'm sending `fetch()` requests from **within** Node.js, not from a browser. The code below produces the following output:

```
Login session ID: um2RykooJCer7Oy7YmJQs7s9ge3mZWL1
Products session ID: uAk03ochUM56rzJjPvbiRnFuPG8CUqTB
Products response: Error: Not logged in
```

It can be seen that the session IDs are different, that's why it fails to show products. When I leave the code running and type in the API calls manually in a browser:

```
http://localhost:3000/login
http://localhost:3000/products
```

Then the code works correctly, with the browser displaying "**Login OK**" and then "**Apple, Orange, Pear**" both with the same session ID.

So the question is: How can the server test be made to work correctly with `fetch()` from Node.js, the same way as it works when called from a browser? Are there some options that can be given to the `fetch()` requests or to Express? I have not found any yet.

Bonus question: Can it also be made to work with the npm package node-fetch? I use that because the built-in `fetch()` from Node.js gives errors in other places.

PS I'm using the most recent versions of Node.js (v21.5), Express, express-session and node-fetch.

```
import Express from "express";
import Session from "express-session";
// Uncomment this to use the node-fetch module, but gives the same result:
// import fetch from "node-fetch";

declare module 'express-session' {
    interface SessionData
    {
        loggedIn: boolean;
    }
}

class App
{
    express = Express();

    start()
    {
        let session = Session( { secret: "my-secret", /* options? */ } );
        this.express.use( session );
        this.express.get( "/login", ( request, response ) => this.onLoginRequest( request, response ) );
        this.express.get( "/products", ( request, response ) => this.onProductsRequest( request, response ) );
        this.express.listen( 3000, () => this.requestLogin() );
    }

    // =================================== Login

    requestLogin()
    {
        fetch( 'http://localhost:3000/login', { /* options? */ } )
            .then( result => this.showProducts() );
    }

    onLoginRequest( request: Express.Request, response: Express.Response )
    {
        console.log( "Login session ID: " + request.session.id );
        request.session.loggedIn = true;
        response.send( "Login OK" );
    }

    // =================================== Products

    showProducts()
    {
        fetch( 'http://localhost:3000/products', { /* options? */ } )
            .then( result => this.onProducts( result ) );
    }

    onProductsRequest( request: Express.Request, response: Express.Response )
    {
        console.log( "Products session ID: " + request.session.id );
        if( !request.session.loggedIn )
            response.send( "Error: Not logged in" );
        else
            response.send( "Apple, Orange, Pear" );
    }

    onProducts( result: any )
    {
        result.text()
            .then( ( text: string ) => console.log( "Products response: " + text ) );
    }
}

( new App() ).start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a browser, add this option to your `fetch()` call:

```
{ withCredentials: true }
```

Without that, `fetch()` may not send cookies with the request.  Without the cookies, there is no connection to an existing session so Express creates a new empty session on each new request.

If you're using `node-fetch()` server-side, then you will need some sort of cookie jar that collects and retains cookies from one request to the next.  Nodejs, unlike a browser, does not collect and keep track of the cookies for you.  There a [module `node-fetch-cookies`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch-cookies) that does that for `node-fetch` code.  You can also manually collect a returned cookie off a response and then send that cookie back with the next request (the same way a browser would).

Comment: Thank you very much! In detail, for reference: I replaced the import of module "node-fetch" with "node-fetch-cookies" and added a shared CookieJar instance as the first argument to the 2 fetch() calls. Now the session ID remains the same with the second API call and producs are displayed.

Comment: Because node-fetch-cookies had a dependency issue for me in the real app, I ended up implementing your second suggestion to manually collect and set cookies. In the `onLogin()` method added `this.cookie = response.headers.get( 'set-cookie' );` and in the `requestProducts()` method added init options to the fetch() like this: `const init = { headers: { cookie: this.cookie } }; fetch( 'http://localhost:3000/products', init );` . Thanks again.

Comment: OP is asking for Nodejs, not Browser

Comment: @user2226755 - Yes, that's why I referenced `node-fetch()` in my  answer.  You may not realize that the original question (before all the edits it has seen) did not make it entirely clear where the `fetch()` call was being made from which is why my answer covered both possible situations.

Comment: ok, this makes more sense :)